# Lack of protein?

Tags: protein-shakes

At the end of skiing season last year I decided to reduce my fat intake and started eating fruit and veggies for breakfast and lunch. This year I find I have much less stamina on the slopes. After a couple of runs my thighs start burning after descending only 100 yards down a slope and I have to rest a bit.

Comment: This is far too vague and broad of a question for any answer to be of any value.

Comment: We eat too much proteins this days. I saw BBC program, they showed that 15% more proteins from shake goes to trained quad. One leg was working, and they have marked proteins. Then they did test on group of people showing that you don't need it. Since normally you provide enough proteins, and muscle grow happens in time... One more point is that if there is enough proteins, or carbs, we are not taking them all. When you go down - then your body learns how to go deeper. I've heard that yo-yo effect comes from that.